# Search in site contents by php

Tags: php

I use codeigniter.I want search in site contents for several word, that did existence it word in it site or no? if existence a word (of all words) in it site return is FALSE. i tried as following code but get error. How can done it?

**DEMO:** http://codepad.viper-7.com/rFiL01

```
<?php
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'stackoverflow.com');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $contents = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $link[] = array("Questions", "Favorite", "myfoodho");
                foreach($link as $val){
                    stristr($contents,$val); // Line 148
                    //if(){
                    //      return true;
                    //}else{
                    //    return false;
                    //}
                }
?>
```

Error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: stristr() [function.stristr]: needle is not a string or an
>   integer
>
> Filename: views/exchange.php
>
> Line Number: 148

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write

```
$link[] = array("Questions", "Favorite", "myfoodho");
```

you are creating an array that contains another array, that is:

```
array(
    0 => array(
        "Questions", 
        "Favorite",
        "myfoodho"
    )
)
```

In the foreach loop you're just going through the outer array and therefore `$val` contains the inner array, not the string values.

The solution is to remove the brackets and just assign the array to the variable.

```
$link = array("Questions", "Favorite", "myfoodho");
```

---

Debugging tip: The error message says *"needle is not a string or an integer"*. The "needle" of that function is the second parameter (check [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) if you're not sure). You can then add `var_dump( $val )` right before that line to check what the value actually is, if it's not a string or an integer.